# php Парсинг таблицы футбольной Лиги süper lig

Tags: php, парсер

При помощи curl и [simple_html_dom](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) пытаюсь получить значения Турецкой футбольной лиги в файл. Но пока не получается

```
<?php

function curl_get($url, $referer = 'https://www.google.com'){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
include_once ("libs/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");

$html = curl_get('https://www.google.com/search?q=s%C3%BCper+lig+puan+durumu+2022&rlz=1C1SQJL_trTR954UA954&ei=4q7CYpqLEImGxc8P1bWbCA&oq=s%C3%BCper+lig+puan+durumu&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYATIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYATIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYATIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYATIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYAUoECEEYAEoECEYYAVAAWABgzw5oAXABeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQDIAQ3AAQHaAQYIARABGAk&sclient=gws-wiz#sie=lg;/g/11mx3297nc;2;/m/04r98r;st;fp;1;;');

file_put_contents('1.html', $html);
```

Ссылка вроде правильная, но парсер забирает не то что нужно...(Нужно тот список из 20-и команд что получает по нажатию на кнопку See more) и не на том языке, необходимо на турецком.
Подскажите, как поправить парсер ?  Эта раскрытая плашка, это какой-то динамический элемент ?

[image: Турецкая Лига]

Comment: А что конретно не получается то?

Comment: 1) Если ввести просто в URL браузера указанную ссылку, то отображаеться всё как надо, а по факту парсер скачивает в файл не ту страницу 2) Не тот язык при парсинге, нужен турецкий... думал что язык зарыт в ссылке, но пока не нашел

Comment: Язык скорее всего зашит во фреймворке (судя по дизайну скорее всего Angular). Так что не факт, что Вы вытянете что-то без подгрузки скриптов

Comment: а можно больше подробностей, только познаю парсинги в php... Это необходимо что б парсер перешел по ссылке, нашел нужный элемент, инициализировал подгрузку нового контента и уже потом скачал ?

Comment: Если сайты с подходом SPA, то сначала должны прогрузиться скрипты, потом можно выдирать какие-то элементы. Если работает серверный парсер - он должен выполнять скрипты самостоятельно (v8 в помощь). Сильно проще делать это при помощи NodeJS, там в этом плане проще намного (можно воспользоваться puppeteer или playwright, они умеют ренндерить страницы до конца)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=s%C3%BCper+lig+puan+durumu+2022&rlz=1C1SQJL_trTR954UA954&ei=4q7CYpqLEImGxc8P1bWbCA&oq=s%C3%BCper+lig+puan+durumu&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIHCAAQRxCwAzIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYATIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYATIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYATIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYATIKCAAQ5AIQsAMYAUoECEEYAEoECEYYAVAAWABgzw5oAXABeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQDIAQ3AAQHaAQYIARABGAk&sclient=gws-wiz#sie=lg;/g/11mx3297nc;2;/m/04r98r;st;fp;1;;  Как определить есть ли там SPA ? Это просто гугл страница

Comment: А, вы прямо с гугла тянете. Ну у гугла вроде всё рендерится нормально, но не факт, что гугл вам не подсунет что-то другое просто чтобы не тянули инфу. Посомтреть можно по просмотру кода страницы (ПКМ и выбрать пункт в браузере). Всё что видно - стянет любой парсер (PHP через cURL в том числе). Всё, что там в исходниках не видно - рендерится

Comment: Данные наверняка загружаются не сразу на страницу, а в последствии тянуться аяксом и скорее всего есть какой-нть сеансовый токен, который по истечении времени перестает работать, поэтому лучше пользоваться апи гугла или поискать другой сайт, где есть эти данные.